# HTML/CSS image hover - using different sized images

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, web-standards

So what I have is this website:
http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/
If you hover with the mouse on the social images on the footer, which are in a table, you'll see that smaller images change to bigger and move the layout. How to avoid/fix this? No matter of CSS/HTML/JS just I need to solve this. My code:

```
<table class="social" align="center" height="40" width="40">
<tr>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 auto;">
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#later_to_add">
<img src="/resources-backups/rss-inactive.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/resources-backups/rss-active.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/resources-backups/rss-inactive.png';" alt="rss-feeds" />
</a>
</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 auto;">
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#later_to_add">
<img src="/resources-backups/youtube-inactive.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/resources-backups/youtube-active.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/resources-backups/youtube-inactive.png';" alt="youtube" />
</a>
</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 auto;">
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#later_to_add">
<img src="/resources-backups/twitter-inactive.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/resources-backups/twitter-active.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/resources-backups/twitter-inactive.png';" alt="twitter" />
</a>
</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 auto;">
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#later_to_add">
<img src="/resources-backups/facebook-inactive.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/resources-backups/facebook-active.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/resources-backups/facebook-inactive.png';" alt="facebook" />
</a>
</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 auto;">
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#later_to_add">
<img src="/resources-backups/google-plus-inactive.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/resources-backups/google-plus-active.png';" onmouseout="this.src='/resources-backups/google-plus-inactive.png';" alt="google-plus" />
</a>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also can I have a fiddle with the code changed to the new standarts (HTML5, CSS3, etc..). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can *we* have a fiddle?

Comment: [Don't Use Tables for Layout](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm)

Comment: **Welcome! Please keep in mind that every content on this fan-site is protected by the USA Copyright Law!** Sorry, can't help anymore.

Comment: add borders to the new images to make them the same size.

Comment: the easiest way would be to make the hover image the same size as the original image.

Comment: use <ul><li></li></ul> instead of your table,it's bad practice

Comment: Also what's the reason for voting down on my question? I'm not a HTMl/CSS developer, I'M LEARNING and I need to ask when I don't know something however easy it look's to you negative voter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set these css attributes to the element holding the Images:

```
Position:relative;
height:(Here put in pixels the height of your element)px;
```

setting a height will force it to stay static to that height.

Answer (score 0):

Give your table a `min-height`:

Change this line :

```
<table class="social" align="center" height="40" width="40">
```

To :

```
<table style="min-height:64px;" class="social" align="center" height="40" width="40" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put padding or margin on the images, then remove the padding/margin on hover

Answer (score -1):

Give `z-index` to the `<div>`containing images.